# Syntax error in Where Clause using .format in arcpy.Select_analysis

Tags: arcpy, select, error-000358, arcgis-10.6, where-clause

I'm having a little trouble understanding the syntax for a Where Clause; e.g., for use in `arcpy.Select_analysis(inSHP, clipSHP, where)`.

input is polygon shapefile; Zone_ID field is short integer

This works:

```
whereClause = '"Zone_ID"= ' + str(zone)
```

But this doesn't:

```
whereClause = "{field} = '{val}'".format(field = Zone_ID, val = zone)
```

Throws this error:

```
NameError: name 'Zone_ID' is not defined
```

"Zone_ID" is obviously defined because it works in the first case. Any ideas what's wrong with my syntax?

Tried this also:

```
whereClause = "{field} = '{val}'".format(field = "Zone_ID", val = zone)
```

Error message:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Zone_ID = '1'
Failed to execute (Select).
```

Comment: What data type is ZoneID field

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify the data source (shapefile?) Different formats require different strings.  If the Zone_ID field is numeric, you cannot quote the comparison value.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on
>   the format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

Since your field is integer you should have no " or ' surrounding the value:

```
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\features'
fieldname = 'ZoneID'
whereClause = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname),123)
...
```

Should make your `whereClause` look like this:

```
>>whereClause
'"ZoneID" = 123'
```